# How Can I Get Adjacent Pairs of Combination Using R?

Tags: r, combinations

Given a list of characters, such as:

```
L <- list("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Note that, the length of `L` is not fixed.

How can I get adjacent pairs of combination, such as:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  "a"  "b" 
[2,]  "b"  "c" 
[3,]  "c"  "d"
```

Actually，I do this job to get a directed matrix for further network analysis. U know, in a specific computer-mediated communication, people discuss with each other one by one, there is a sequence, new comer only reply to the latest post.

Comment: All pairwise combinations, or just adjacent pairs?

Comment: You will have to give more information: how will you specify _which_ combinations you want? We can answer you how to get _this_ set of combinations (I assume you want the combinations that are 1 apart in your list), but not how to get _any specific_ combination without knowing what will define these kinds of combinations.

Comment: To specify my question, thanks to the reminding above. I just want to get the adjacent pairs!

Comment: Maybe (1) edit your question to reflect this preference for only adjacent pairs (and the fact that you already know about `combn`) and (2) take this small bit of direction for future SO questions [welcome!] -- including a few more details about what you already know can help people answer you more efficiently.

Comment: +1 For responding to feedback and editing your question to become very clear.  And for providing sample data and expected results. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrie's use of embed is certainly elegant and probably more efficient. Here's a slightly more clumsy method:

```
> L<-c("a", "b", "c", "d")
> L
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
> matrix(c(L[-length(L)], L[-1]), ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c" 
[3,] "c"  "d"
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful for dealing with NULL values, such as:        L<-letters[1]

Comment: +'s back at you. I still like yours better, but it's good that the customer has what he needs.

Answer (score 6):

Use `embed`

```
> L <- letters[1:4]
> embed(L, 2)[, 2:1]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c" 
[3,] "c"  "d"
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to `embed` which I hadn't seen/used before.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `combn`:

```
L<-c("a", "b", "c", "d")

combn(L, 2)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "c"  "d"  "d"
```

You can subset from there depending on what you need.

Comment: I know this function, Thank you for your kindly answer. The following question is how to subset from it?                                    I am wondering how to write a function to fulfill the whole process. For example, using the length(L) as a condition.

Comment: To specify my question, thanks to the reminding above. I just want to get the adjacent pairs!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with `cbind`:

```
L <- letters[1:4]
cbind(head(L, -1), L[-1])
```